# search and replace with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to search a keyword into body and replace it with a link if it is already not linked to somewhere. My code is :

```
var search = $('body').html();
search = search.replace(/jQuery/g, function($1){
    return('<a href="http://jquery.com">' + $1 + '</a>');
});

$('body').html(search);
```

The problem is, it replaces all keyword even if it is already linked.

I dont want to replace if it is already linked.

can anyone suggest me, what to do....

Comment: Use a parser instead of RegEx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery selectors to search for links.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var links, search;

    $links = $('a[href=http://jquery.com]');

    if ($links.length) {
        search = $('body').html().replace(/jQuery/g, function($1){
            return('<a href="http://jquery.com">' + $1 + '</a>');
        });

        $('body').html(search);
    }
});
```

If you only want to replace on the first instance of "jQuery", remove the `g` modifier from your regex.

Comment: The entire point of the question is that these strings are NOT in links. - OP wants to search the HTML and replace `blah` with `<a href="...">blah</a>` and also leave all `blah` s that are already in links untouched.

Comment: Ah, I was reading it as he wanted to create links only if there wasn't already a link anywhere on the page.  What you say makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

- Select all text nodes that do not have `<a>` parents.
- Find the regex in the text nodes only and do the replace

  ```
  var regex = /jQuery/g;
  // Get all text nodes:
  var $textNodes = $("*").contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3 && 
          $(this).parent("a").length === 0;
  });


  // Iterate through the text nodes, replacing the content
  // with the link:
  $textNodes.each(function(index, element) {
      var contents = $(element).text();
      contents = contents.replace(regex, "&lt;a href='http://www.jquery.com'&gt;jQuery&lt;/a&gt;");
      $(element).replaceWith(contents);
  });
  ```

I do **not** recommend using the "*" selector, as it will cause performance issues.  Replace that selector with something that is more accurate (for example, if you're looking for text inside of `<p>, <span>, <div>`, you could write `$("p span div")`